# VS2013 git - Project marked as pending delete

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013

I recently wanted to try VS2013 and the Git tool for SC. Everything worked great until I did something, but dont know what...
I created a nodejs application and pushed it to github. However, the "main" script was not directly into the root repo directory, so I manually created another repo to be able to push it to heroku. Well,
after that, another branch appeared in team explorer, and my master branch was told that all files were in a pending delete status. I sync the repo and it was well pushed into github however I must do it manually because I got an error in VS. Now that the repo is pushed, I dont have any error anymore when Sync, but there are still those pending delete status on every files.

Furthermore, because of that, I cant do any change in a file and push it with VS, I must push manually.

Any idea ? (I know the issue is really not clear, but I do my best ;))

Answer (score 4):

Simply right-clicking the problematic file/project in the VS solution explorer and selecting Undo did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

A few hours ago, I had the same problem/symptom as you, and now everything is fine.  I'm not sure if what I did solved the problem or if it's a normal "glitch".

Here's what I did:

1. I deleted all bin and obj folders in Windows Explorer
2. I used Git GUI to commit this delete and push it to github
3. I re-opened the project in VS2013 and everything is fine

Pat

Answer (score 0):

It's late but I also want to give some idea . I had same prob , Git set pending delete status for all files . I have just included .gitignore file with config :

```
node_modules 
bower_components
```

And It worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, my controller files were marked "Pending Delete" and I was wondering if anyone else had deleted them.
So I went to the Controllers folder in Windows Explorer, right clicked, and selected "Undo Move". Somehow I must have moved these files accidentally.
So if you see any pending deletes, check if your files were accidentally moved (or deleted) first.

Answer (score 0):

Actually some file have been deleted or some changes have been made. So go to git changes & in the changes section you may find those respective files. Right click and undo changes. This will restore back the files and no "pending delete" option may occur! Worked for me , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just did a git reset!

```
git reset
```

P.S: The above command can undo any changes that you've made in the repo. Please ensure you understand the consequences before running the same.